# Pass more data to session in Next-auth after Google sign in

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using the Google Provider to allow users to login to my website. My code in /api/auth/[...nextauth].js like this:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'

const fetchUserInfo = (email) => {
    // Get user info in database by google email
}

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Providers.Google({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn(user, account, profile) {
            if (account.provider === 'google' &&
                profile.verified_email === true &&
                profile.email.endsWith('@example.com')) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/signin',
    },
    secret: process.env.SECRET
})
```

I want to execute function `fetchUserInfo` after user has been authenticated. `fetchUserInfo` get the user's information from database, and i want to save it to the session so i can use it later. The default session i have is the information returned by google are: `email`, `name`, `image`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you have to rewrite the default session in callbacks :

```js
...

async session({ session }) {

    const userInfos = await fetchUserInfo(session.user.email);


    session.user = userInfos;
        

    return session;
},
...
```